Transaction 0x6a19aa91361ce2b93b7515962821540af2aab0ebff0fcdcb90ee252fbe64c107 is pending: true
Any insight into this?
I am attempting to deploy a smart contract using Go-Ethereum but it is pending forever until my context timeout.
In order to minimize the complexity I use a worthless contract.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract Nothing {
   constructor() {
   }
}

When I deploy the contract using Remix it works and it used Gas Price
1.508696653 Gwei (0.000000001508696653 ETH).
But when I deploy it using the code below it uses Gas Price
1.68873408 Gwei (0.00000000168873408 ETH) which is more than the properly deployed contract.
package deploy

import (
    "arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/connection"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/structs"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/util"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/wallet"
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func Run(params structs.DeploymentParam) {
    value := big.NewInt(0)
    fmt.Println("Contract deploying...")
    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(wallet.Sepolia.PrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("Not OK " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA)
    nonce, err := connection.RPC.Client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    pendingBalance, err := connection.RPC.Client.PendingBalanceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    suggestedGasPrice, err := connection.RPC.Client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }
    actualGasPrice := new(big.Int).Mul(suggestedGasPrice, big.NewInt(20))

    fmt.Println("suggestedGasPrice: ", suggestedGasPrice)
    fmt.Println("actualGasPrice: ", actualGasPrice)

    contractString := util.GetContractBIN(params.Name)
    contractBytecode := common.FromHex(contractString)

    contractABI, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(util.GetContractABI(params.Name)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse the contract ABI: %v", err)
    }
    var data, constructorArguments []byte

    constructorArguments, err = contractABI.Pack("") //
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to pack constructor arguments: %v", err)
    }

    data = append(contractBytecode, constructorArguments...)

    // Estimate gas limit
    msg := ethereum.CallMsg{
        From:     fromAddress,
        To:       nil, // To is nil for contract deployment
        Gas:      0,
        GasPrice: actualGasPrice,
        Value:    value,
        Data:     data,
    }

    gasLimit, err := connection.RPC.Client.EstimateGas(context.Background(), msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Failed to estimate gas: %v", err)
        gasLimit = getBlockGasLimit()
    }

    //check sufficient funds
    cost := new(big.Int).Mul(actualGasPrice, big.NewInt(int64(gasLimit)))
    fmt.Println("pendingBalance: ", pendingBalance)
    fmt.Println("cost: ", cost)
    fmt.Println("ETH cost: ", util.WeiToETH(cost))
    if pendingBalance.Cmp(cost) < 0 { //pendingBalance < cost
        fmt.Println("Insufficient funds, have ", pendingBalance, " need ", cost, " ", whereami.WhereAmI())
    }

    fmt.Printf("Gas Price Wei: %s\n", actualGasPrice)
    fmt.Printf("Gas Limit: %d\n", gasLimit)

    chainID, err := connection.RPC.Client.NetworkID(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to get network ID: %v", err)
    }

    tx := types.NewTx(&types.LegacyTx{
        Nonce:    nonce,
        To:       nil,
        Value:    value,
        Gas:      gasLimit,
        GasPrice: actualGasPrice,
        Data:     data})

    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.NewEIP155Signer(chainID), privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to sign transaction: %v", err)
    }

    // Send the transaction
    err = connection.RPC.Client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to send transaction: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(signedTx.Hash().Hex(), "waiting to be mined...")
    go network(signedTx.Hash().Hex())
    startTime := time.Now()
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Hour)
    defer cancel()
    receipt, err := bind.WaitMined(ctx, connection.RPC.Client, signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error() + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
    }
    fmt.Println("Mining took", time.Since(startTime))
    fmt.Println("Token tx:", tx.Hash(), "?????")
    fmt.Println("Token cost:", tx.Cost())
    fmt.Println("Token gas limit:", tx.Gas())
    fmt.Println("Token gas price:", tx.GasPrice())
    structs.OnChainContract.Tx.GasLimit = tx.Gas()
    structs.OnChainContract.Tx.GasPrice = tx.GasPrice()
    structs.OnChainContract.Tx.Hash = tx.Hash().Hex()
    structs.OnChainContract.Tx.Cost = tx.Cost()

    if receipt.Status == types.ReceiptStatusSuccessful {
        structs.OnChainContract.Receipt.Address = receipt.ContractAddress.Hex()
        structs.OnChainContract.Receipt.GasUsed = receipt.GasUsed
        structs.OnChainContract.Receipt.Hash = receipt.TxHash.Hex()
        structs.OnChainContract.Receipt.Block = receipt.BlockNumber
        fmt.Println("Token deployed successfully at", receipt.ContractAddress)
    } else {
        reason, err := getRevertReason(receipt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error() + whereami.WhereAmI())
        }

        if len(reason) == 0 {
            fmt.Println("No receipt reason found " + whereami.WhereAmI())
            network(receipt.TxHash.Hex())
        } else {
            log.Fatal(reason + " " + whereami.WhereAmI())
        }
    }
}

func getRevertReason(receipt *types.Receipt) (string, error) {
    if len(receipt.Logs) == 0 {
        return "", nil
    }

    // Get the revert event signature
    revertEventSig := []byte("Error(string)")

    // Iterate through the receipt logs to find the revert event
    for _, receiptLog := range receipt.Logs {
        if len(receiptLog.Topics) > 0 && bytes.Equal(receiptLog.Topics[0].Bytes(), revertEventSig) {
            if len(receiptLog.Data) < 32 {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("invalid event data")
            }

            // Extract the revert reason from the event data
            revertReason := string(receiptLog.Data[32:])
            return revertReason, nil
        }
    }

    return "", nil
}


When running the code I get
Contract deploying...
suggestedGasPrice:  84436704
actualGasPrice:  1688734080
pendingBalance:  4979114636516930574
cost:  114700507447680
ETH cost:  0.00011470050744768
Gas Price Wei: 1688734080
Gas Limit: 67921
0x6a19aa91361ce2b93b7515962821540af2aab0ebff0fcdcb90ee252fbe64c107 waiting to be mined...
Pending transactions: 63
Suggested gas price: 84436704
Transaction 0x6a19aa91361ce2b93b7515962821540af2aab0ebff0fcdcb90ee252fbe64c107 is pending: true

This is the ABI
{constructor() returns() map[] map[] map[]  }

And the BIN
6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b50603f80601d6000396000f3fe6080604052600080fdfea2646970667358221220d1b84972956a56ab82acb41e0c0c2332cf1fc742601dd4be78965861b4755d2b64736f6c63430008140033

The ABI and BIN are compiled using these commands.
docker run -v /home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy:/sources ethereum/solc:0.8.20 --allow-paths=/sources/sol-flattened -o /sources/solc-output --optimize --optimize-runs 200 --evm-version london --overwrite --bin --abi /sources/sol-flattened/Nothing.sol
Compiler run successful. Artifact(s) can be found in directory "/sources/solc-output".
abigen --abi /home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/solc-output/Nothing.abi --bin=/home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/solc-output/Nothing.bin --pkg=api --type=Nothing --out=/home/user/Documents/crypto-projects/arbitrage-bot-v2-flattened-contract-solc-abigen-deploy/api/Nothing.go

